# Multiple threads Inserting rows into table in Grails

Tags: multithreading, grails, grails-orm, executorservice

I am attempting to insert multiple rows of data into a table through a multiThreaded program in a standard Groovy-Grails application. The application uses standard GORM objects for database interaction. Each thread inserts a different set of rows. I am using ExecutorService and FixedThreadPool in a Grails Service that invokes Runnable Groovy class. The Runnable class queries DB, does a lot of computation and inserts the derived values into a table. I am running into the following exception.

```
`Error java.lang.NullPointerException
```

`Error at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)`
    `Error at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:85)`

Here's the Runnable class.

```
@Transactional
class MyRunnable{
  def aService
  def bService
def run(){
  for (i=1; i<n; i++){//n is a finite integer
   def x = aService.doSomething()
   def y = bService.doSomething(x)
   AGormClass.addToBGormClass(y)
  }
  AGormClass.save flush:true
 }
}
```

Here's Grails Service that initializes thread pool and calls Runnable class.

```
@Transactional
class SvcClass{
  ExecutorService exeSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
  MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable()
  exeSvc.execute(runnable as Runnable)
  exeSvc.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: I am using Grails 2.4.4